# Flutter in app purchase with backend side calling completePurchase and verifyReceipt

Tags: ios, flutter, in-app-purchase, in-app-subscription

I have a flutter mobile app with a backend. I need to synchronize subscription with backend to share subscription across platforms.

For that I follow this flow :

- I create a new account
- I initiate new subscription after account has been created
- I listen for purchase update and when I receive a purchase details with `purchaseDetails.pendingCompletePurchase` I send it to backend and use apple verifyReceipt endpoint to check receipt in `purchaseDetails.VerificationData.ServerVerificationData`
- If receipt is valid I save the OriginalTransactionId from `purchaseDetails.PurchaseID` to database

My question here is:
After it return validation state from server I wonder if I still need to call `completePurchase` even if I called verifyReceipt endpoint.
I'm not sure to understand what completePurchase really do...

- In the end, later I wait for apple server notification to update subscription status

Comment: Yes, you always need to call complete transaction on the device, otherwise the transaction is pending and will be re-presented to your transaction observer the next time your app starts

Comment: @Paulw11 ok I see. Thanks. And so I will receive first apple server notification only if I call complete ?

Comment: Thats correct.  Until you complete the purchase the user isnt charged and you don't get any money

Comment: ok, thanks for those informations